execute command buffering issue
        cmd = 'cat <file1>'
        time.sleep(5)
        result = device.execute(cmd, timeout=200)
        time.sleep(5)
        output=result.strip()
        print(output)

I am running a command on the device with device.execute("cat "), and the output is stored in a variable called output. Occasionally, the output doesn't buffer correctly, causing the command to fail when I try to run the next one. It seems to be a buffering issue. I’ve set a timeout of 200, but that hasn’t resolved the problem. How can I fix this?

The problem is not in the shown code, but in the definition of device.execute. Make sure you include a complete example
